# write a program that computes and displays the factorial of a positive integer n entered by the user

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf, factorial

Been working on this question for class. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Seems like I just don't have the correct format. My professor wants the output to look like "5!=1 * 2* 3* 4* 5=120"

Can someone help me with this? Below is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, fact;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: \n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.");
    else {
        for( i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            fact *= i;
            n= n * (n-1);
        }
        printf("Factorial of %d = ", &n, &fact) ;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do amything with `n` inside the loop.

Comment: Even without that, if the input by the user is 4, the output is Enter a positive integer: 
4
Factorial of 1363373000 =, how would i make it look like how my professor wants it answered? @MuhammadMuaaz

Comment: @misfit101 Those magic `&` signs are just for `scanf`, not for `printf`.

Comment: Oops! Sorry @SteveSummit, this is my first coding class. Still trying to learn!

Comment: Make sure you enable verbose warnings in your compiler. It should warn you about the type mismatch there.

Comment: Hint: What's the value of `fact` when you enter the loop?

Comment: @misfit101 No worries — the fact that `scanf` dupes you into wrongly using `&` elsewhere is #12 on its list of 17 annoying problems.  `scanf` is the bastard stepchild of the C Programming language: its only real use is in "starter" programs like yours, yet it's so hard to use that only a grizzled old veteran has any hope of using it correctly.  (But grizzled old veterans understand how useless it is, and don't bother with it at all.)

Comment: @dbush I am new to coding and we just started this unit, my best guess is 0. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @misfit101 If you don't know for sure, that's a good indication you have a problem.

Comment: Very true @dbush, sorry for my ignorance. I am trying to learn.

Comment: @misfit101 So then how can you be sure of what the starting value is?

Comment: I don't think I am following you, @dbush

Comment: @misfit101 If you don't know what the initial value is, maybe you should give it one.

Comment: @dbush, okay, I understand now that I have to give fact a value of 1. When I input a positive integer I get a huge number back, if you look above to how the professor wants the output, i am confused on how to get this result. Also, in my class we haven't learned about unsigned integer types yet.

Comment: @misfit101 Don't worry about someone's caution that "signed int does not make sense" — it's fine, for you, for now.

Comment: @misfit101 Improve debug reporting.  Rather than "When I input a positive integer I get a huge number back", report the input value and the output result.

Comment: You got that huge number because (a) you used `&` with `printf` and (b) you forgot to initialize `fact` and (c) you had that unnecessary line `n= n * (n-1);` in the loop..  Once you fix those problems, you should start getting a sensible answer.  Now you just have to worry about printing (printing, not computing) the text `"1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5"`.

Comment: @misfit101 Save time.  Good compilers, when warnings are fully enabled, will warning about code `printf("Factorial of %d = ", &n, &fact) ;`.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove `#include <iostream>` if it is the `C` code
2. Use functions.
3. Initialize local variables (you do not and it is undefined behaviour)
4. Compile C program using C compilers

```
unsigned long long fact(unsigned val, char *buff)
{
    unsigned result = 1;
    *buff++ = '1';
    *buff = 0;
    for(unsigned c = 2; c <= val; c++) 
    {
        buff += sprintf(buff, "x%u", c);
        result *= c;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x;
    char y[1000];
    unsigned long long res;

    if(scanf("%u", &x) == 1){res = fact(x, y); printf("factoral(%u) = %s = %llu\n", x, y, res);}
    else printf("Invalid number!!!\n");
}
```

or without printing steps

```
unsigned long long fact(unsigned val)
{
    unsigned result;
    switch(val)
    {
        case 0: 
        case 1:
            result = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = 2;
            break;
        default:
            result = 2;
            while(val > 2) result *= val--;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned x;

    if(scanf("%u", &x) == 1) printf("factioral(%u) = %llu\n", x, fact(x));
    else printf("Invalid number!!!\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tf5431zco

Answer (score -1):

For starters it does not make a sense to declare the variable n as having a signed integer type. It is better to declare it as having unsigned integer type. For example

```
unsigned int n, i, fact;
```

Secondly the variable fact was not initialized. You should initialize it by the value equal to 1.

So the above declaration could look like

```
unsigned int n, i;
unsigned long long fact = 1;
```

In this for loop

```
    for( i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        fact *= i;
        n= n * (n-1);
    }
```

the statement

```
        n= n * (n-1);
```

does not make a sense and shall be removed.

In the printf call you have to use values of variables instead of pointers to the variables like

```
printf("Factorial of %u = %llu\n", n, fact) ;
```

Pay attention to that neither declaration from the header `<iostream>` is used in your program So whether it is a C program or a C++ program nevertheless remove this header.

Here is a demonstration C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned long long int fact = 1;

    printf( "Enter a positive integer: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    printf( "%u! = ", n );

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        fact *= i;

        if ( i != 1 ) printf( " * " );

        printf( "%u", i );
    }

    printf( " = %llu\n", fact );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a positive integer: 5
5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
```

If you are allowed to use only variables of the type `int` as you wrote in a comment to the answer then the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int n = 0;
    int fact = 1;

    printf( "Enter a positive integer: " );
    scanf( "%d", &n );

    if  ( n  <  0 )
    {
        puts( "Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist."); 
    }
    else 
    {
        printf( "%d! = ", n );

        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            fact *= i;

            if ( i != 1 ) printf( " * " );

            printf( "%d", i );
        }

        printf( " = %d\n", fact );
    }   
}
```

To output multipliers in the reverse order like

```
5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120
```

rewrite the for loop the following way

```
    for ( int i = n; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        fact *= i;

        if ( i != n ) printf( " * " );

        printf( "%d", i );
    }
```

Comment: The weird part is that we have never used unsigned integer types in this class. So I'm unsure of what the professor will say. Also, we have not learned %u or %llu.

Comment: @misfit101 See my appended answer.

Comment: Signedness will make no difference in the context of this homework assignment; your professor will know better than to try factorial on anything that would overflow an int.

Comment: "not make a sense to declare the variable n as having a signed integer type. " --> agree `unsigned` is useful here, yet "not make a sense" is an overstatment.  Even with `unsigned long long`, only inputs in the 0 to 20 (or so) range are reasosnable.  OP nicely does peform a lower bound check on input.

Comment: Okay, that works. But now, I have to output the other way. Example: 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1= 120 How would I do this?